# Variable as bash array index?

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

array_counter=0
array_value=1

array=(0 0 0)

for number in ${array[@]}
do
    array[$array_counter]="$array_value"
    array_counter=$(($array_counter + 1))
done
```

When running above script I get the following debug output:

```
+ array_counter=0
+ array_value=1
+ array=(0 0 0)
+ for number in '${array[@]}'
+ array[$array_counter]=1
+ array_counter=1
+ for number in '${array[@]}'
+ array[$array_counter]=1
+ array_counter=2
+ for number in '${array[@]}'
+ array[$array_counter]=1
+ array_counter=3
```

Why does the variable **$array_counter** not expand when used as index in array[]?

Comment: What's it not doing that you expect?  After your loop, array is "1 1 1"

Comment: I would expect the debug output to show array[0]=1, array[1]=1 and so on.

Comment: ah, you're just worried about the debug output.  I'm actually surprised it works at all without an `eval`, but it could be that lhs arrays are expanded differently.

Answer (score 35):

Bash seems perfectly happy with variables as array indexes:

```
$ array=(a b c)
$ arrayindex=2
$ echo ${array[$arrayindex]}
c
$ array[$arrayindex]=MONKEY
$ echo ${array[$arrayindex]}
MONKEY
```

Comment: ...and since array indices get evaluated in an arithmetic context you don't even need `$`, you can even do things like `${array[arrayindex-1]}` which validly refers to `b`.

Answer (score -1):

Your example actually works.

```
echo ${array[@]}
```

confirms this.

You might try more efficient way of incrementing your index:

```
((array_counter++))
```