# Access array element using independent variable in bash script

Tags: arrays, bash

Usual arrays are looped over using the indices. For my application I need to use an independent variable to extract values from array.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Author : Ankit
echo "Please enter the number of files (max index number of file): "
read iv
fname="t3p_"
echo "You entered: $iv, $fname" ;
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Reference values
refxa=(2.0 3.0 4.0)
refza=(1.0 6.0 7.0)
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
rm result.txt
#echo  $iv,$fname
i=1
while [ $i -lt $(($iv+1)) ] ;  do
xxn=5
zzn=19
refxn=$(echo $refxa | awk '{print $i}')
refzn=$(echo $refza | awk '{print $i}')

delta_x=`echo $xxn - $refxn  | bc -l`
delta_z=`echo $zzn - $refzn  | bc -l`

printf "%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n" "$i" "$xxn" "$delta_x" "$zzn" "$delta_z" >>  result.txt

i=$[$i+1]
done
echo -e  "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
cat result.txt
```

My question :

1. As seen above I want to subtract value `xxn` from ith array element(`$i`) which is the index of the loop. How to access the array element using the variable `$i`. (Using array index is not an option since in my script $i is related to several other parameters and that code is not shown here.)

I tried `${refxa[i]}` which did not work.

Expected output (3rd and 5th column are  `xxn-refxn[i]` and `zzn-refzn[i]`:

```
You entered: 3, t3p_
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1.000000        5.000000        3.000000        19.000000       18.000000
2.000000        5.000000        2.000000        19.000000       13.000000
3.000000        5.000000        1.000000        19.000000       12.000000
```

Comment: Please provide desired / expected output.

Comment: You know that `${refxa[i]}` is not valid and it has to be `${refxa[$i]}`, right?

Comment: The answer in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856132/variable-as-bash-array-index) does not work in my case and I don't know why.

Comment: Also tried `${refxa[$i]}` which did not work either.

Comment: Hm... you said: `ith array element($i) which is the index` ... later `Using array index is not an option` ... bogus. Anyway - in bash the arrays has zero-based indexing - e.g. the first element is `${arr[0]}`.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou : Tried that and it works

Comment: Got my answer. The array loops from 0 to n-1, while i was thought it to be from 1 to n. Fixed it and it works fine.

Comment: @jm666 We learnt something new today. Your sample code works ok , thanks.